# Scraping Github commit author element

Tags: html, r, github, web-scraping, rvest

Any html whizzes out there able to extract the text for an element on this link: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2

The element text required is [image]

Am currently using rvest in r. Have tried xpath, css etc but just unable to extract the user name. Quite happy to take a link containing the name and cleanse the text using regex if needed.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give it a shot and post your code, the community here doesn't take too kindly to requests like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rvest)

read_html("https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2") %>%
  html_nodes(".user-mention") %>% 
  html_text()

# [1] "thomasp85"
```

But if you are trying to grab information from multiple repos, you may want to consider using the official [GitHub REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) and/or [this lightweight R package client](https://github.com/r-lib/gh).

Comment: I should acknowledge you further for your suggestion of the API @JasonAizkalns . This has really helped.